# Cant break out of login system

Tags: python, loops, authentication

The login system i have wont break out of the loop. I have shown this to my CS teacher and he told me to change the indentations of the break. It didn't work. I have been looking around but I can't seem to find a reason as of why the loop wont break. Here is the code:

```
while True:
    print("User 1")
    login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
    loggedin=False
    if login.lower()=="yes":
        login1=open("login.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(login1)
        username1=input("What is your username: ")
        password1=input("What is your password: ")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==username1:
                if row[1]==password1:
                    print("Welcome " + username1)
                    loggedin=True
                    break
        if loggedin==False:
            print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
            continue
```

The code asks if the user has an account. When I input yes and give valid username and password, it continues with the loop. For context when the user logins in, it says welcome and breaks out of the loop. However this isn't happening, it is instead saying welcome and restarting the loop. The csv for this contains the login details.

Any help as of why the loop wont break will be greatly appreciated.

Dylan

Comment: Is it how the code is **actually** indented?

Comment: You should indent your code starting from the second line, i.e. the line after `while True:`.

Comment: We don't know the content of your csv file and we do not know the user inputs, thus we cannot help you until you provide a [mcve]. And ``break`` will only exit the inner most loop, which in your case is the ``for`` loop, not the ``while`` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? I mean you already have a "loggedin" variable, why not use it in the while loop...

```
loggedin = False
while not loggedin:
    print("User 1")
    login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
    loggedin=False
    if login.lower()=="yes":
        login1=open("login.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(login1)
        username1=input("What is your username: ")
        password1=input("What is your password: ")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==username1 and row[1]==password1:
                print("Welcome " + username1)
                loggedin=True
                break
        if loggedin==False:
            print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `break`.

You break out of the for loop, but never the while loop.

Try this:

```
while True:
    print("User 1")
    login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
    loggedin=False
    if login.lower()=="yes":
        login1=open("login.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(login1)
        username1=input("What is your username: ")
        password1=input("What is your password: ")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==username1:
                if row[1]==password1:
                    print("Welcome " + username1)
                    loggedin=True
                    break
        if loggedin==False:
            print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
            continue
        if loggedin==True:
            break
```

EDIT:

Personally, i would avoid using a `while True` and instead do something like this:

```
loggedin = False
while not loggedin:
    print("User 1") # Consider moving this outside of the while loop too
    login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
    if login.lower() == "yes":
        login1=open("login.csv") # Consider moving this outside of the while loop too
        reader = csv.reader(login1) # Consider moving this outside of the while loop too
        username1=input("What is your username: ")
        password1=input("What is your password: ")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==username1 and row[1]==password1:
                print("Welcome " + username1)
                loggedin = True
                break
        if loggedin==False:
            print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
```

Note here that the `continue` is not needed.